# In how many ways can $2n$ balls, two each of $n$ different colors, be placed in $n$ indistinguishable boxes so that two balls are placed in each box?

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

> $\; \; \; \; \; $There are $2n$ balls with $n$ different colors, two for each color. (Balls of the same color are the same), and there are $n$ identical boxes. Now, we put all the balls into all the boxes, and each box happens to have two balls. Regardless of the order of the boxes and the order of the balls inside the boxes, how many different placement methods are there?

When $n = 2$, there are $2$ methods: $1.AA\; BB$$2.AB\; AB$.

When $n = 3$, there are $5$ methods: $1.AA\; BB\; CC$$2.AB\; AB\; CC$$3.AC\; BB\; AC$$4.AA\; BC\; BC$$5.AB\; BC\; AC$.

$\; \; \; \; \; $At first, I thought it was simple. Isn't this the order of a permutation group? Later, I discovered that $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &3 \\
2 & 3 &1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &3 \\
3 & 1 &2
\end{pmatrix}$ are the same,all equal to $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &2 \\
2 & 3 &3
\end{pmatrix}$,so there are only $5$ situations when $n=3$.$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &3 \\
1 & 2 &3
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &3 \\
2 & 2 &3
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &2 \\
3 & 3 &2
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &2 \\
1 & 3 &3
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &2 \\
2 & 3 &3
\end{pmatrix}$.

I calculated the number of $n \le 5$, which is $1, 2, 5, 17, 63$.  Then I typed it into OEIS, but couldn't find the answer I wanted. Did I make a mistake or did I discover a new sequence?

Comment: Are you saying that there are two balls each of $n$ types?

Comment: What I understand is that there are 2n distinct balls and n identical boxes. Is this correct ? Further does order within a box matter ? Pl. Clarify these points

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake when calculating n=5
, and the answer is 73
. I now know the answer, and the answer is OEIS A002135.[link](https://oeis.org/A002135)